# Move from google app engine to virtual machine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, virtual-machine

I had as an assignement to create a website. I did it on google app engine. I use jinja2 and google database.

Now, my proffesor ask to move it from google app engine to a virtual machine. Probably, I have to rewrite the part of google database with a mySQL for example.

How exactly I setup the libraries, files and templates in the virtual machine? Do you know any tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method would be to install the AppEngine SDK on the virtual machine and run your AppEngine app on the local dev server. See:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver

Comment: If I do it with that way, can I give my own domain and anyone have access?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Who doesn't have access? What are you tryiing to do that you couldn't do on AppEngine?

Comment: Sorry for that. I write it fast and english is not my mother language. If I do what you say, will I have access to the site only local or can I set a domain name and use it like a simple website? Thank you for your time. If anyone else suggest something better than this, I will choose your answer as the best asap.

Comment: No problem. Take a look at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Command_Line_Arguments .  If you specify --host 0.0.0. and --port 80 as command line parameters then the site will be accessible to anyone who can connect to the Virtual server.

Answer (score 0):

I had success with the TyphoonAE image and ran it on VMware
https://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/
Worked with the mongoDB out of the box.

Comment: Did you need to change your code? I am using GAE database and I don't want to change all the parts with the DB